# Powershell csv creating a new column with 2 others

Tags: powershell

Here is my script so far. I want to create a new column called `password` but only use the first letter of column `Associate_First_Name`, the  first letter of `Associate_Last_Name` and the last 4 of `Associate_SIN_SSN`. How do I only pull certain values from a column?

```
$CSV = import-csv "C:\csv" | select Associate_First_Name,Associate_Last_Name,Associate_Email,Associate_SIN_SSN,@{n=’password’;e={$_.Associate_First_Name+ $_.Associate_Last_Name+ $_.Associate_SIN_SSN}}

$CSV | export-CSV "C:\csv"-NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
$CSV = Import-Csv "C:\csv" |
    Select-Object Associate_First_Name,Associate_Last_Name,Associate_Email,Associate_SIN_SSN,@{n='Password';e={$_.Associate_First_Name.Substring(0,1).ToLower()+ $_.Associate_Last_Name.Substring(0,1).ToLower() + $_.Associate_SIN_SSN.Substring(($_.Associate_SIN_SSN.Length-4))}}
```

To extract parts of a string, you can use the .NET method [Substring()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8) from the String class.

---

You can slightly enhance readability by defining your calculated property before the `Select-Object` command. Also a String value is indexed and individual characters can be extracted using an index (`[0]` is the first character).

```
$Password = @{n='Password'
              e={ $_.Associate_First_Name[0] + $_.Associate_Last_Name[0] + $_.Associate_SIN_SSN.Substring(($_.Associate_SIN_SSN.Length-4)) }
}

$CSV = Import-Csv "C:\csv" |
        Select-Object Associate_First_Name,Associate_Last_Name,Associate_Email,Associate_SIN_SSN,$Password
```

---

Another readability alternative is to not use calculated properties with `Select-Object` and create custom objects instead. This also adds flexibility to manipulate each value before outputting them.

```
$CSV = Import-Csv 'C:\csv' | ForEach-Object {

    $First = $_.Associate_First_Name.ToLower()
    $Last = $_.Associate_Last_Name.ToLower()
    $Email = $_.Associate_Email.ToLower()
    $SSN = $_.Associate_SIN_SSN
    $Password = $First[0]+$Last[0]+$SSN.Substring(($SSN.Length-4))

    [pscustomobject]@{ 'Associate_First_Name' = $First
                       'Associate_Last_Name' = $Last
                       'Associate_Email' = $Email
                       'Associate_SIN_SSN' = $SSN
                       'Password' = $Password
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you that worked, am i able to format that so that it's all lower case?

Comment: Yes. I added the `ToLower()` method to the password string.